# PHP foreach loop to print out html listbox options

Tags: php, mysql, listbox

Here goes my first post.

I am currently pulling two fields out from my MySQL database with a fetch all and am trying to get the data in those fields to become options in a listbox.

This is my code:

```
<fieldset class="contact"> 
<legend>Select a Band</legend>
<!-- Drop List -->    
<select id="lst1" name="lst1" tabindex="281" size="1">

    <?php
     foreach ($bands as $band) {
        $name = $band["fldBand"];
        $id = $band["pkID"];
        $options .= '&lt;option value="' . $id . '"&gt;' . $name . '&lt;/option&gt;';
     }
     echo $options; 
    ?>

</select>
```

and here is the result of echoing out $options:

```
<option value="1">Rise Against</option><option value="2">Alter Bridge</option><option value="3">Falling In Reverse</option><option value="4">Saosin</option><option value="5">Pennywise</option><option value="6">The Killers</option><option value="7">Thrice</option><option value="8">Four Year Strong</option>
```

I want to have the foreach loop print out the code that will be the options for my listbox lst1 but it is currently not working. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
     foreach ($bands as $band) {
        $name = $band["fldBand"];
        $id = $band["pkID"]; ?>
      <option value = "<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>

    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. In your code '&lt' and '&gt' makes html entity format. So html does't accept   it as a tag.

```
<select id="lst1" name="lst1" tabindex="281" size="1">

    <?php

     foreach ($bands as $band) {
        $name = $band["fldBand"];
        $id = $band["pkID"];
        $options .= '<option value="' . $id . '>' . $name . '</option>';
     }
     echo $options; 
    ?>

</select>
```